# How set True or False?

Tags: php, mysql

How to check if True Or False?

I have this script

[/ code]

```
     <? php
@ $ db = mysql_connect ("localhost", "admin", "admin");
@ mysql_select_db ("project challenger", $ db);
if (isset ($ _GET)) {
$ test = $ sql = "INSERT INTO suggestions SET title = '". $ _GET [' title ']. "', suggestion = '". $ _GET [' suggestion ']. "'";
mysql_query ($ sql) or die (mysql_error ());
}
}
 
?>
```

How do I check whether it has submitted the data into the database via my form and then give it a TRUE or FALSE statement so that I can use it to redirect or w.e?

Comment: `$Var = true;` or even.. I know it's insane, `$Var = false;` ;')

Comment: Should use mysqli really also

Comment: False, Daryl, that would be setting the value to true or false, not checking it. To check the value you'd use == (equal) or === (strict equal) or != (not equal)

Comment: Please, can you explain it a little better? I dont get it..

Comment: @GaryHayes Question title "how set true or false", first comment sums it up

Comment: Pascal, your script is VERY vulnerable to an attack, I suggest you read up more on $_GET and $_POST before going live with the site, and learn about filtering user input.

Comment: Pascal, you should read up on booleans and how to interact with them. Your code above already has an example, 'if (isset ($ _GET))' what that really means is 'if $_GET equals true' or 'if $_GET has a value', if $_GET has no value (not set), it is equal to false, or zero (0).

Comment: @DarylGill You don't bother reading the question body?

Answer (score 2):

The docs are helpful.

> "INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error."

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Also, read the big red warning on that page and consider switching to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Just assign its value to a variable, or check directly... `$all_good = mysql_query(...` or `if (mysql_query(...` Think of it just like any other function with a return value.

Comment: `if (mysql_query($sql) === false) { echo 'Insert failed';} else { echo 'Insert succeeded';}`